# How to make docker-compose stop after X containers have stopped?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, end-to-end

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file that spins up 11 containers:

- 1 container runs a web application that I want to test
- 10 near identical containers run a bunch of end to end tests that target the first container

Only after all 10 test containers have finished running all their tests, I'd like `docker-compose` to spin down all 11 containers.

Does `docker-compose up` support this sort of functionality or do I need to build my own on top of it?

Comment: afaik, docker-compose (which is wrapper) does not support this. but writing a small script thats checks availability of containers docker-compose in-network isn't really hard.

Comment: You might be able to do this with healthchecks.

Comment: @dov-rine thanks. `healthcheck` is interesting, but how do I make it check the other 9 containers from within each one of them?

Comment: @urig: You don't. If you need containers to check on each other, then you need to use Butuzov's answer. Docker-compose doesn't reach into the containers; it orchestrates their construction, operation, and tear-down.

Comment: @urig: You could use a combo by creating a script that reports each container's health based on their test progress and have docker-compose use that script for the healthcheck.

Comment: @DovRine tx again. I don't think that'll be needed as I just need each container to run a node program until it exits with 0 or 1. The missing bit is how to wait for all 10 to finish. Currently thinking of `docker-compose events` for this.

Comment: How are you running the containers and tests with `docker-compose`? That should be simple enough if you ensure the process running in your tests containers are exiting with a 0 code after test. Provide your `docker-compose` and `Dockerfile` and we'll be able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 11 containers (let's say they are called `a_1`, `a_2`,  ... ,`a_11`) and you need to wait for 10 of them (let's say the first 10) then 
you can do the following using the command [docker wait](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/wait/):

```
docker-compose up -d
docker wait a_1 a_2 ... a_10
docker-compose down
```